# Using View Controller as the delegate for an auxilliary view fails with unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have a View Controller called CompanyTableView that is not the main View Controller - although this maybe irrelevant

CompanyTableView has a function

```
func getNxtKey() -> Int {
    return Int(CDM.getMaxID())
}
```

That function calls a function on a shared instance data model class called CDM.

I am trying to call the function from an auxiliary view controller by using the CompanyTableView as delegate - this is the view controller that calls the auxiliary view

In the auxiliary view controller I have:

```
var delegate: AnyObject?
```

and then:

called by an add button:

//Button to add new contact or save edit

```
 @IBAction func btnAddCompany(_ sender: Any) {
  //i have used the following code:

    ic = (delegate as! CompanyTableView).getNxtKey()
```

Execution fails at this point with the error unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping an optional

Comment: Where did you initialize `delegate` property?

Comment: I have just realised my mistake. I did not set in prepare for segue that destination controller delegate was self

Comment: You can answer your own question.Could be useful for other developers.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Stack Overflow so apologies that I didnt know the etiquette of answering your own questions.

The mistake I made was that in the prepare for segue I not not specified that that the delegate for the destination view controller was self.

With code as follows:

//Set the destination controller and pass the representedobject as repObj
                let auxView = segue.destinationController as! 
                AddCompanyController
                auxView.delegate = self
                auxView.representedObject = repObj

Once I added auxView.delegate = self all worked as expected